# SELECT and lock a row and then UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that selects a row from MySQL database.
Then updates this row. Like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT id, link from persons WHERE processing = 0");
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch();

$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE persons SET processing = 1 WHERE id = :id");
$success = $statement->execute(array(':id' => $row['id']));
```

The script calls this php code multiple times simultaneously. And sometimes it SELECTS the row eventhough it should be "processing = 1" because the other script call it at the exact time.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? To update the `unprocessed` rows? or any other conditions attached?

Comment: I want to do SELECT and UPDATE on the same time. I want to avoid that this row can be selected as processing = 0 by another query because the UPDATE query was not done yet. I want to avoid this race.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is add some kind of lock here to prevent race conditions like the one you've created:

```
UPDATE persons SET processing=1 WHERE id=:id AND processing=0
```

That will avoid double-locking it.

To improve this even more, create a lock column you can use for claiming:

```
UPDATE persons
  SET processing=:processing_uuid
  WHERE processing IS NULL
  LIMIT 1
```

This requires a `VARCHAR`, indexed `processing` column used for claiming that has a default of `NULL`. If you get a row modified in the results, you've claimed a record and can go and work with it by using:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE processing=:processing_uuid
```

Each time you try and claim, generate a new claim UUID key.

Comment: Isnt keeping a lock on the db using a field, way costlier and messy?

Comment: @ngen Not really. This scales to hundreds of thousands of records without any real effort. Pulling one row out of a table with an index is pretty much zero overhead. There is no way you want to use database-level row locks. That's asking for disaster, especially if you need to leave a transaction hanging open to make it work. If you choose claim keys with meaningful data in them you can backtrace to the thing that claimed it easily enough, useful for debugging. A transaction will hide the in-progress work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using transactions for your queries. Read about them at the [mysql dev site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html)

You can wrap your code with:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

// ... your transactions here

$dbh->commit();
```

You'll find the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT FOR UPDATE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

eg

`SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;`

Wrap this in a transaction and the locks will be released when the transaction ends.

Comment: So when I do `SELECT id, link from persons WHERE processing = 0 FOR UPDATE` this row will be locked? So the script calls this query almost simultaneously again it can't select this row?

Comment: But does this lock all rows where processing = 0 or only the record I am selecting? If it locks all records does it help if I use `LIMIT 1` ?