# How to get the max value of two joined variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I thing I am getting this wrong. I have two variables, one is to get date and month and the other is for number (000). I concatenated the two variables together and set it to another variable then insert it into the database. So what I want to be updating the column in order to have unique no for each receipt.The receipt no format is (14-07000) do is to get the maximum value of the column the inserted variable and add 1 to it each time it finds a new max value. But I am not getting exactly what I needed. It is inserting as I want but not updating. I want the receipt no column to be 14-7000). Then start updating to 14-07001, 14-07002, 14-07003, 14-07004, 14-07005, 14-07006,14-07007 etc. So tomorrow, it can change to 15-07000 and next month, it can change to 15-08000.

This is the code I used

```
  <?php
    // pass the data into the database
    $tran_id1 = date('d-m');
    $tran_id2 = "000";
    $transaction_id = $tran_id1 . $tran_id2;



  if (empty($received & $amount_to_pay & $amount_collected) == false)
  {

    $sql8 = "INSERT INTO `transactions` (`patient_name`,`total_amount`, `amount_tendered`, `payment_status`, `payment_date`, `paid_for`,`hospital_no`, `received_by`,`receipt_no`) VALUES ('$received', '$amount_to_pay', '$amount_collected', '$payment', '$payment_date', '$being_pay_for','$hosp_no', '$firstname','$transaction_id')";
    $query8 = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql8) or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));
    $sql9 = "INSERT INTO `transaction_paid_for` (`paid_for_name`) VALUES ('$others')";
    $query9 = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql9) or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));
    $max = "SELECT  MAX(`receipt_no`) AS transaction_id FROM `transactions`";
    $max2 = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $max);
    $result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($max2);
    $result2 = $result1['transaction_id'];
    $result3 = $result2+1;
    $sql = "UPDATE `transactions` SET `receipt_no`='$result3' WHERE `patient_name`='$received'";    
    $result4 = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);  
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you cannot use such mathematical calculations on a varchar field. A good alternative is to store the d-m in a separate varchar column and the incrementing number in an int column.

You can then use code to get the required receipt number.

```
//create 2 columns in your table eg dm and receipt_no    
//to store tran_id1 & tran_id2 into dm and receipt_no columns
$tran_id1 = date('d-m');
$tran_id2 = "000";

// Create connection & select
$sql = "SELECT MAX(receipt_no)+1 MAX_RECEIPT_NO FROM transactions WHERE dm='" . $tran_id1 . "' LIMIT 0,1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);   
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tran_id2 = $row["MAX_RECEIPT_NO"];
}
//create your receipt no
$transaction_id = $tran_id1 . str_pad($tran_id2, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
//now use sql update with this $transaction_id
```

Note:

- Your code didn't take the year into account.
- You may want to avoid duplicates so put a unique constraint on the 2 columns
- Also you can wrap the sql in transactions or use a separate column for locking, see [SELECT and lock a row and then UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996307/select-and-lock-a-row-and-then-update).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but I want it to be adding to the maximum receipt no 1 at every point.

Comment: My code `SELECT MAX(receipt_no)+1` already adds 1 to the maximum receipt no. Alternatively you can simply retrieve MAX and add 1 in your php code.

Comment: Yes.... Thanks. Please is there a way to perform arithmetic on `date ('d-m')`  function? Like adding 1 to it

Comment: In that case you can use separate columns for d and m instead of one column of dm. This way you can perform arithmetic functions. But according to your question you wanted day-month followed by serial number, so the code `$tran_id1 = date('d-m');` already gets current day and month.